# Getting Flask to use Python3 (Apache/mod_wsgi)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mod-wsgi

I've got a basic "hello world" Flask app running.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04,  using Apache 2.4.  I've installed mod_wsgi.

I've created a `~/web/piFlask/venv/` to hold a virtualenv-created Python2 with flask installed.

However, I wish to have my flaskapp import a Python3.x module I have written.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

I tried creating a `~/web/piFlask/venv3/` and modifying `~/web/piFlask/piFlask.wsgi`:

```
import os, sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/home/pi/web/piFlask'

activate_this = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'venv3/bin', 'activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

from piFlask import app as application

application.debug = True
```

But I don't think this is sufficient. This .wsgi is in fact a Python file that will get executed by mod_wsgi, which I'm sure will use a Py2.x interpreter to do the execution.

So if I'm understanding correctly, mod_wsgi fires up the system Python in order to execute this .wsgi, which will in turn fire up my `~/web/piFlask/venv/` interpreter to actually process the request.

I think I could persuade mod_wsgi to use either a system Python3 or my own venv3/... by setting `WSGIPythonPath /home/pi/web/piFlask/venv3/lib/python3.4/site-packages` in /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.conf

But I found an instruction somewhere saying you have to compile mod_wsgi for Py3, and the bottom quickly falls out to this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct, mod_wsgi needs to be compiled for a specific Python version as it never actually executes 'python' executable. Instead the Python library is linked into mod_wsgi.

The end result is you cannot mix Python 3 code within an application running using the Python 2 interpreter.

You would have to consider making your code runnable under both Python 2 and 3 and then you could choose which of those you want to use and use a version of mod_wsgi compiled for the version you choose to use.

Comment: I'm going to target just Python3. It looks as though there is `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` -- could I instead do: 1. a2disable mod_wsgi, 2. uninstall mod_wsgi using pip, 3. install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 using pip3?

Comment: Yes. So long as all your code and any third party Python modules you need are Python 3 capable. Everything will need to be installed in your Python 3 virtual environment. You cannot mix parts from virtual environments for different Python versions.

Answer (score 15):

Took me awhile, although it was really simple in the end.  Unfortunately I've lost my bash history so if you find a mistake, please leave a comment or edit in the correction.

Note that I had already got mod_wsgi working, so I had to remove it:

```
$ a2dismod wsgi
$ sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

EDIT: Due to apt-get installing an outdated package (which results in a minor error creeping into Apache's error log) I don't at time of writing recommend this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
$ a2enmod wsgi
```

Instead, first set up your py3 virtual environment, (and might as well in install Flask into it while you're at it)

```
$ pip install virtualenv

$ cd ~/web/flaskapp
$ virtualenv -p python3 ./venv3
$ source ./venv3/bin/activate     #  enter virtual environment
$ pip install Flask
```

Now follow [Installing mod_wsgi for Python3 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674644/installing-mod-wsgi-for-python3-on-ubuntu/30682386#30682386) to install mod_wsgi into this venv, and ...

```
$ deactivate                      #  ... & exit
```

This was from the original apt-get approach, now it is not relevant:

> Now I have to make `mod_wsgi` use this new Py3:
>
> ```
> $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.conf
> ```
>
> And do:
>
> ```
> #WSGIPythonPath directory|directory-1:directory-2:...
> WSGIPythonPath /home/pi/web/flaskapp/venv3/lib/python3.4/site-packages
> ```

Finally I need to modify my ~/web/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi so that it now supports Python3:

```
$ cat web/piFlask/piFlask.wsgi

# http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file
# http://www.enigmeta.com/2012/08/16/starting-flask/

# for Py3:
# http://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1

import os, sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/home/pi/web/flaskapp'
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)


def execfile(filename):
    globals = dict( __file__ = filename )
    exec( open(filename).read(), globals )

activate_this = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'venv3/bin', 'activate_this.py' )
execfile( activate_this )


from piFlask import app as application
application.debug = True
```

Just a reminder of how Apache uses mod_wsgi to execute this file when the user points their browser to http://myfoo.org/flask:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
:
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskProcess user=pi group=pi threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /flask /home/pi/web/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

<Location /flask>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskProcess
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Location>
:
```

Discussion: It seems a bit messy that I am installing mod_wsgi module into Apache, but it resides in a venv3 which is inside my flaskapp folder.  But this is at least ensuring Apache -> mod_wsgi -> (uses the correct i.e. venv3 Python) -> {to launch my FlaskApp}.

The alternative would be to update the system Python, and use that instead of venv.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I spent lots of hours trying to find a way to run mod_wsgi on python 3. What I didnt know was that there's a specific version for python 3. Thumbs up

Comment: Wonderful! This is a well-written answer to this sort of question.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the P i's answer. The following now works and fixes the problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
$ a2enmod wsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

I started running python3.5.2 with flask 0.12 in a venv on a Ubuntu 16.04 (virtual machine).

@Graham pointed out activating the the venv from the WSGI script file is not the preferred way. More info here: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Just for anyone else looking for info on this I'm putting all your steps together: 
*Note: my app name is blazing, path ~/jan/blazing. Replace them with your own.*

```
sudo apt install python3-pip

sudo apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv ~/blazing/venv
source /home/jan/blazing/venv/bin/activate

pip3 install --upgrade pip    
pip3 install Flask

sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
(venv) pip3 install mod_wsgi
(venv) sudo venv3/bin/mod_wsgi-express install-module
```

OUTPUT:
LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/home/jan/blazing/venv"

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.load
```

ADD: LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.conf
```

ADD:

```
WSGIPythonHome "/home/jan/blazing/venv"
WSGIPythonPath /home/jan/blazing/venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages
```

then

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi_express

vim /home/jan/blazing/project/flaskapp.wsgi
```

ADD:

```
import os, sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/home/jan/blazing' sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

activate_this = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'venv/bin', 'activate_this.py' )
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this)


from piFlask import app as application application.debug = True
```

and

```
vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/flask.conf
```

ADD:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskProcess user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /flask /home/jan/blazing/project/flaskapp.wsgi

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_flask.log #you can see the errors here..
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_flask.log combined

<Location /flask>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskProcess
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Or if you have other sites running and would like to have flask as one of the Virtual hosts, you can use this conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName flask.ubuntuws
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_flask.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_flask.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskProcess user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jan/blazing/project/flaskapp.wsgi

    <Location />
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskProcess
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

and make sure your `PROJECT_DIR` in `flaskapp.wsgi` points to your **PROJECT_NAME**.py. 
enable the virtual site and reload apache:

lastly:

```
sudo a2ensite flask.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Suggest you read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for preferred way of using a virtual environment. Activating it from the WSGI script file is not the preferred way. You also don't need ``WSGIRestrictStdout Off`` as that is the default.