# installing wsgi_module debian

Tags: python, pip, wsgi

I can't install wsgi_module using pip. I got the following error.

Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
Pip version : pip 10.0.1 (python 3.4)

```
root$ pip3 install wsgi_module
Collecting wsgi_module
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/1c/decce9bf785d96d3a1b791b33f2d7b1939d916dc67868e1145ec44e5c13a/wsgi_module-4.0b4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-62ltkhsl/wsgi-module/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
    INCLUDEDIR = get_apxs_config('INCLUDEDIR')
  File "/tmp/pip-install-62ltkhsl/wsgi-module/setup.py", line 36, in get_apxs_config
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'apxs'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-62ltkhsl/wsgi-module/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674644/installing-mod-wsgi-for-python3-on-ubuntu ?

Comment: thanks you. i found this answer, and it works for me: **sudo apt-get install apache2-dev then pip install mod_wsgi was all I needed to do; no reboot required – @Nick Aug 4 '15 at 20:48**